# How can you remove duplicates inside an element (based on comma separation)?

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), `Column1` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `Column2` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2007", 
"2014, 2011", "2007"), `Column3` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", 
"2011", "2007"), `2005` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30", "18", NA), `2006` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2007` = c("15", NA, "18", NA, "30, 18", NA), `2008` = c("16", 
NA, NA, "30, 27", "18, 30", NA), `2009` = c("15", NA, NA, "20", 
"30, 18", NA), `2010` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30, 20", NA, NA), `2011` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2012` = c(NA, NA, NA, "20, 30", NA, "26"), `2013` = c("15", 
NA, "19", NA, NA, NA), `2014` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA), 
    `2015` = c(NA, NA, "18", NA, "18", NA), `2016` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), .Names = c("ID", "Column1", 
"Column2", "Column3", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to remove duplicate entries for every row. So for example in the first row, there are 4 elements with values: 15, 16, 15, 15. I'd like for R to remove the value of the last two elements since those are duplicates.

The part that gets tricky for me is row 4, where I have the elements "30", "30, 27", "20", "30, 20", "20, 30". Even though "30, 27" is inside the same element, I still want to treat the two numbers as separate. So because "30" was mentioned in a previous element, I want R to remove the "30" in the next element so it simply says "27".

This would be the final output:

```
structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), `Column1` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `Column2` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2006, 2006, 2005, 2005, 2007", 
"2014, 2011", "2007"), `Column3` = c("2011", "2015", "2015", "2005", 
"2011", "2007"), `2005` = c(NA, NA, NA, "30", "18", NA), `2006` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2007` = c("15", NA, "18", NA, "30", NA), `2008` = c("16", 
NA, NA, "27", NA, NA), `2009` = c(NA, NA, NA, "20", 
NA, NA), `2010` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2011` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), `2012` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "26"), `2013` = c(NA, 
NA, "19", NA, NA, NA), `2014` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `2015` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "18", NA), `2016` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), .Names = c("ID", "Column1", 
"Column2", "Column3", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been trying for a while with different functions like `duplicate` and `unique` but I'm having problems with the vectors inside the elements.

Comment: In row 4, why are entries for `2010` and `2012` `NA` in your expected output? The source entries in `df` are `2010 = "30, 20"` and `2012 = "20, 30"`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers: That is because "30" was in 2005 and "20" was in 2009, so they're all duplicates afterwards!

Comment: So you assume that specific values can only occur once across all years? In other words, you assume that different years can never have the same value? That sounds odd to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Base R solution:*** *Element wise check for each row:*

```
df_temp <- apply( df[,5:ncol(df)], 1, 
               function(x){
               temp <- unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(x, collapse = ","), split = ","))))
               temp <- temp[!is.na(temp)]

               y <- rep(0,length(temp))
               names(y) <- temp

               new_x <- x
               i <- 1

               for (item in x){
                              temp2 <- unlist(strsplit(item, split = ", "))
                               if (is.na(item[1]) == FALSE){
                               for (item in temp2) { if (y[item] == 0) { 
                                                        y[item] <- 1
                                                        } else { temp2[which(temp2 == item)] <- NA } 
                                                   }
                              new_x[i] <- ifelse(length(temp2[!is.na(temp2)]) == 0, NA, paste0(temp2[!is.na(temp2)], collapse = ", "))    
                                                           }
                              i <- i + 1
                              } 
                       return(new_x) 
                          } )

df_output <- cbind(df[,1:4], t(df_temp))
```

*PS: Was just feeling like using base R today. Ignore warnings*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.  I tried to write it such that it will paste together results if/when both "30, 20" don't appear previously.

```
df %>% 
  gather(year, value, `2005`:`2016`) %>% 
  mutate(
    value = str_split(replace_na(value, 0), ", ")
    ) %>% 
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(
    value = replace(value, value == 0, NA)
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, year) %>%
  summarize(
    value = paste(value, collapse = ", ")
  ) %>%
  spread(year, value, fill = NA)
```